# Reuse Geb Pages for multiple domains

Tags: geb

I'd like to test the search functionality of 30 websites that are generated by the same CMS under different domains with different Lucene-indexes. For this purpose I'd like to write a single Page Object which I'd like to be fed by the configuration with those 30 different baseUrls.

I'd be running those tests in the same environment so I'm not sure how to approach this issue. Is there anything I've been missing so far? Looking forward to a push in the right direction and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the base url in your test using `using browser.config.baseUrl = 'http://example.com'`. It will be reverted to the value configured in `GebConfig.groovy` for the next test.

The question is how many tests do you wish to run this way? If it's just one test then you can get away by using Spock's support for parametrised tests with `where:` block and this approach. If it's more than one test then you will probably be looking at custom test runners or running your tests multiple times using your build system with different geb environment settings.